# Aligning Nested Table Widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some nested tables.  There is the main, outer table, it has to nested tables for the left and right columns, and in each column some tables are stacked on top of each other.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the tables in the column to all span the same width (mostly in the right column).  Here is the HTML, scaled down for readability:

```
<table class="outer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="column" id="left_column">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t1">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t2" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:86px">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="column" id="rightColumn">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t3">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t4">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t5">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t6">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t7">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t8">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="messages" id="t9">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.outer
{
margin: auto;
}
.column
{
border: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
table.cell
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
#rightColumn table
{
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to nail down table column widths, use the `table-layout: fixed` CSS property on the `table` and specify widths for all of the cells in the first row (or use `col` elements if you're starting with no first row).

Answer (score 0):

So the CSS I had was valid.  Firefox had actually cached an older CSS for this page.  The widths went to 100% as soon as I cleared the cache.